# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysql.so'

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

i'm using laravel framework with xampp server but when i execute

`php artisan serve`

this error showing for me :

> PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mysql.so' - The specified module could not be
>   found.  in Unknown on line 0

Comment: this post doesn't solve my problem because talk about different problem i have a problem in  \php_mysql.so .

Comment: It doesn't matter which module is loaded more than once, the problem is the same.

Comment: Ok I understand you , but that doesn’t solve my problem cos i used external libraries .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **php.ini** file and set the setting to a Windows file path:

```
extension_dir = "X:/path/to/your/php/ext"
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn’t solve problem

Comment: After doing this, restart xamp, If you get error again, please error message paste here

Comment: I did no change

Comment: Which operating system, you are using?

Comment: Im using Windows